# TF2 confused about step numbers in LSTM Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm currently trying to implement the authentification Network from [this](https://github.com/qinnzou/Gait-Recognition-Using-Smartphones) with my own Dataset.

[This is my colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13yzsuDJ71ZGAL0NH8vFHCnpM110waxTX?usp=sharing)

It's "working"(Dataset size is still way too small to do any meaningfull testing), but I am confused about something.

The input is of shape (482, 12, 128, 1). 482 amount of samples , 12 sensors, 128 is the signal length, 1 channel

So what I would expect is to have something like:

```
Epoch 1/10
X/482 [===...
```

In the training, or X/batch_size(which I haven't specified as of now).

But it's X/16.
Now 16 is the Sequence length of the LSTM (I have 16 inputs at the LSTM for one sequence, with 128 values each)

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`model.fit()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) without specifying the `batch_size` argument, it defaults to 32.

> **batch_size:** Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32. Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets, generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate batches).

If you divide your number of samples in batches of 32, it needs 16 batches (15 complete ones, and 1 partial one).

```
482/32 = 15.0625
```

So it needs 16 batches to complete 1 epoch, which is why you see the progress as `X/16`.

Comment: aaah that makes sense. 

The similarity to the Sequence length in the LSTM threw me off and I was worried, that I did something wron. Thank you very much :)